# can't properly justify-content in flexbox container

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have some problems to set the justify of items inside my flexbox.

I'm setting this property in container class, but it somehow doesn't affect anything? I can't figure this out, thanks for some help.

jsfiddle->  https://fiddle.jshell.net/n7ts68se/4/

(embedded editor mess something with paddings, so jsfiddle)

I want the items to stick to each other, so I set the 'center' value, but there is still a space left between them, whats wrong?

```
<nav class="main-header">                       
<a id="logo" class="main-button header-logo">                           
    <h4>test logo here..</h4>
</a>
<a id="t1" class="main-button">                         
    <h4> najnowsze standardy.</h4>
</a>
<a id="t2" class="main-button">
    <h4> profesjonalna wspólpraca.</h4>
</a>
<a id="t3"  class="main-button" href="kontakt.php">
    <h4>kontakt</h4>
</a>                                                
</nav>
```

css:

```
.main-header {
display: flex;
justify-content:     center;
margin: 0 0 3em 0;
}
.main-button {
background: rgba(70, 73, 79,0.6);   
margin: 0 auto;
padding: 0 1em;
color: darkblue;
font-size: 110%;
box-shadow: 1px 2px 1px 0px lightgray;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove `margin: auto` on `left/right` from `.main-button`, that is what's making elements behave same as if you set `justify-content: space-around` on flex container.

```css
.main-header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 0 0 3em 0;
}
.main-button {
  background: rgba(70, 73, 79, 0.6);
  padding: 0 1em;
  margin: 0;
  color: darkblue;
  font-size: 110%;
  box-shadow: 1px 2px 1px 0px lightgray;
}
```

```html
<nav class="main-header">
  <a id="logo" class="main-button">
    <h4>test logo here..</h4>
  </a>
  <a id="t1" class="main-button">
    <h4> first. </h4>
  </a>
  <a id="t2" class="main-button">
    <h4> last. </h4>
  </a>
  <a id="t3" class="main-button" href="kontakt.php">
    <h4> after. </h4>
  </a>
</nav>
```